# Unable to create zip file in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, io, zip

I have tried multiple ways to create this zip file in Java/Groovy.   The first couple methods I attempted, from various blogs/postings, resulted in corrupt zip files which could not be opened.  So, I tried this one (below) which looked fairly promising. The sysouts report valid file paths being passed to the FileInputStream.  I am not sure if it is the FQ path being passed to the ZipOutputStream which is causing the problem.  Either way, below is the code, which results in small (188kb) zip file (with no entries) being created. Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

class FileZipper {

    public static void makeZip(Set fullyQualifiedFileNames, String zipFileName, String outDir) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        // These are the files to include in the ZIP file
        Object[] filenames = fullyQualifiedFileNames.toArray();
        String fileSeparator =  (String) System.getProperties().get("file.separator");

        // Create a buffer for reading the files
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        // Create the ZIP file
        String outFilename = outDir + fileSeparator +zipFileName;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        System.out.println("Zipping to file " +outFilename);
        // Compress the files

        for (Object fileName: filenames)
        {
            System.out.println("Adding file: " + fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream((String)fileName);

            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            String[] nodes = ((String)fileName).split("[/[\\\\]]");
            String zipEntry = nodes[nodes.length-1];
            System.out.println("Adding Zip Entry: " + zipEntry);
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry((String)fileName));

            // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            int totalBytes = 0;
            while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) 
            {
                totalBytes += len;
                zos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            System.out.println("Zipped " +totalBytes +" bytes");
            // Complete the entry
            zos.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }

        // Complete the ZIP file
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Groovy, the easiest way is using `AntBuilder`:

```
new AntBuilder().zip(
   destfile: "myfile.zip",
   basedir: "baseDir")
```

or as of Groovy 1.8:

```
ant.zip(destfile: 'file.zip', basedir: 'src_dir')
```

Comment: I am using Groovy (or Java - whichever will work at this point).  I was scratching my head earlier, wondering where the Groovy util to build a zip was (as it seems so archaic to actually be shuffling byte buffers around in 2012...) I did not stumble across this - I will give it a shot. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Yep, this definitely solved the problem.  Much, much more succinct than all the bytestreaming code!

Comment: Hi.. Ziping task is taking more time.. Is there anyway to create a zip with minimum amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried closing the underlying FileOutputStream explicitly to ensure that all data has been  flushed to disk?

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
...
zos.Close();
fos.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks MRAB... I did attempt this (see code mod) and same result.  It's really quite odd.  (This is on Windows 7/64B, FWIW.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code locally and had no problems creating and then opening a zip file.

However, I sometimes used to run into odd issues with the default Java compression utilities, so I started using the Apache Commons compression and have used it since with little difficulty.

Check http://commons.apache.org/compress/index.html for the basic overview, and http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html for specific examples.

Comment: Hm, this is an idea. I saw those in the import suggestions, but I try to stick with standard issue Java when possible.  I will give it a shot for S&G's...  Thanks Kraagenskul ;)